# Save a SecKeyRef Asymmetric Key Pair to disk as a Certificate

Tags: objective-c, macos, x509certificate, pki, security-framework

I have created two SecKeyRef items via SecKeyGeneratePair, but now I would like to turn the public key into a x509 Digital Certificate – and/or both the public and private keys into a PKCS #12 (.p12) certificate – and save it to disk as a file. This way I can do whatever I need to with it, including sending the certificates to other services or computers.

I would prefer to not use the keychain, but even with that I am having some trouble finding good documentation on exactly how to create a certificate out of a pair of SecKeyRefs, and writing them out as a certificate file.

Comment: I just realized that the SecKeyGeneratePair() command I've been calling all this time seems to be storing my new keys in the Keychain automatically. I think this realization may have just opened a lot of doors to finding a solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Security Transforms Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/Introduction/Introduction.htm). It covers most of what you need for this. Some parts (like `SecItemExport`) are not documented in the reference documentation, only in the public header files. But `SecItemExport` is the new 10.7 way to handle this stuff.

Comment: Using `SecItemExport` has an `SecExternalFormat` of `kSecFormatX509Cert`, but this does not seem to work with just a SecKeyRef. You will get an error **SecItemExport failed (oserr=-50)** which is defined as: `errSecParam = -50, /* One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid. */`

Comment: A SecKeyRef is not sufficient information to generate an X509 Cert. I would assume you'd want a kSecFormatPEMSequence for this, passing an array of the two keys.

Comment: Ok, so effectively turning both keys into a PEM sequence. But then how do I go to the next step of creating a Digital Certificate? Or an X.509 Certificate? Or a PKCS #12 Certificate?  I might be able to do without those formats, but as those are standard formats, it seems like there should be a way.

Comment: An X.509 certificate is not just "a standard format" for storing asymmetric keys. It carries a lot of meaning about trust and applicability. Unless you want all that, then don't use a certificate. PKCS#12 isn't a certificate. It's a way to append a certificate and a key into a file. A concatenated list of PEM encoded data is the standard way to store keys.

Comment: Thank you Rob for helping to clear this all up. I was mainly talking about X.509 in it's most basic form, a file/data format, not in it's larger role as a part of Certificate Authority PKI. I was going to use a self signed X.509 as a way to use an existing standard and not have to re-invent the wheel, but I believe you are right, a PEM list may be more appropriate in my case. Also you are right that I was incorrect in calling PKCS#12 a certificate, I was again just attempting to refer to it as a cryptography file format or standard I could use; in doing so I mislabeled it a certificate.

Comment: Do we have similar option available in ios?

Comment: iOS has very poor support for exporting anything. I have traditionally had to do this by hand with OpenSSL (which you must build yourself and statically link).